# How to determine if these graphs are isomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I had this question on my last Discrete exam:

[image: Isomorphic graphs]
(the missing vertex on graph G is vertex d)

I did prove that the graphs were isomorphic, but my teacher said that I matched up my vertices wrong. However, I have tripled checked it and the all the edges match up with the way I matched the vertices.

Can anyone explain to me where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You are correct; your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the teacher was looking for the other isomorphism (with $a \to c'$, $c \to b'$, $d \to e'$, $e \to d'$).  But yours is perfectly good.